# Setting Quarkus Opentelemetry Propagators

Tags: java, quarkus, open-telemetry, jaeger, open-telemetry-collector

I am trying to understand the purpose of setting this property in the application.properties

quarkus.opentelemetry.propagators=tracecontext,baggage,jaeger

I know the tracecontext and baggage are default. Not sure what the jaeger or this property itself does. We have Jaeger collector and i am able to see all the traces/spans without setting this property. Looking at the docs, it seems this has some vital behavior. Any idea what i am missing here and how the flow works without setting this property with jaeger collector

Thank you
SG

Answer (score 0):

`quarkus.opentelemetry.propagators` or the new property for Quarkus v3.x+: `quarkus.otel.propagators` will allow you to use one or more propagation frameworks. In the example you give, headers for  `tracecontext,baggage,jaeger` will be added to the outbound requests.

- `tracecontext` and `baggage` will use the standard [W3C headers](https://www.w3.org/TR/trace-context/#trace-context-http-headers-format).
- `jaeger` will use the [Jaeger native propagation format](https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.21/client-libraries/#propagation-format), which also includes the baggage.

You can say that you are duplicating the context and the baggage data in 2 different formats, on the outbound request. Upon receiving the request, external systems understanding the default W3C will use the `tracecontext` and `baggage` headers, systems understanding Jaeger format will use the data on the `jaeger` header.

For more details check the [quarkus.otel.propagators](https://quarkus.io/guides/opentelemetry#quarkus-opentelemetry_quarkus.otel.propagators) property and the [propagators](https://quarkus.io/guides/opentelemetry#propagators) section of the Quarkus OpenTelemetry guide. There, you can explore guidelines on integrating additional libraries into Quarkus to enable support for non-standard [propagation mechanisms](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/blob/main/sdk-extensions/autoconfigure/README.md#propagator) permitted by the Java implementation of OpenTelemetry.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it working because of the default behavior even when the config is not provided? Also i am still wondering what the difference is with and without jaeger being on the list when we use Jaeger as the collector.

Comment: Yes, the default propagation with `tracecontext` and `baggage` doesn't require to explicitly set the property. If you don't add `jaeger` when using Jaeger as a collector you will not propagate the traces to other services that only understand the Jaeger propagation format but you will still receive trace information from those services. Trace propagation between services is not correlated with sending data to the Jaeger collector... They are 2 different things.